# Python List to Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have started learning python and I have a question. I have a list and I want to convert it to a dictionary. How is it possible?

For example, I have a class:

```
Person (name, surname, age, country)
```

I have created many person objects and added them to a list. However, searching in a list takes too long time so I want to create a dictionary. How can I convert this person list to a dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: Dictionaries are mappings of keys to values.  That means that when you want to get a value out of the dictionary you give it the key and it fetches the value.  What would the key of your dictionary be?

Answer (score 5):

Use a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
# Assusming "person_list" is your list of "Person" objects
name_to_person = { p.name: p for p in person_list }
```

Usage:

```
george_details = name_to_person['George']
print "George is %d years old"%(george_detals.age)
```

Of course, you don't have limit your keys to the members of `Person`. If you want to look up by a combination of `name` and `surname`, for example:

```
 fullname_to_person = { p.name + ' ' + p.surname: p for p in person_list }
```

Comment: I need to set all name, surname, age in dictionary .. 
in this case there will be only names ?

Comment: A dictionary maps keys to values. In this case, the keys will be the names. The values will be the people. So, when you look up `"George"` in the dictionary, you'll find a `Person('George', 'Jones', 81, 'US')`

Comment: @Soulmaster No, the whole object is in the dictionary value. You get the object by name and then have access to all its attributes

Comment: What if the names  are the same?

Comment: Then he might want his values to be lists.

Comment: @Robᵩ Yes it works but when i want to get data like that nameMap.get(name, [])

Comment: Yes it works but when i want to get data like that name_to_person.get(name, [])   I see some errors .

Comment: THIS SOLUTION DOES NOT WORK FOR ME

Comment: @Soulmaster - Please edit your question and add some more details about what you need.